# Persistent Login loop 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, unity, login, xorg, lightdm

Received workstation with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS preinstalled from Dell.
Computer: Dell Precision 3630

Login loop immediately upon open box.

ctrl alt F1 works and I have access to 2 accounts I created and root

======================================================

contents of **.xsession-errors**

upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2697) terminated with status 1

upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2689) killed by TERM signal

upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus

upstart: logrotate main process (2548) killed by TERM signal

upstart: updat-notifier-crash (/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash) main process (2593) killed by TERM signal

hud main process (2687) killed by TERM signal

unity7 pre-start process (2691) terminated with status 143

unity-panel-service main process (2613) killed by TERM signal

bamfdaemon main process (2614) killed by TERM signal

====================================================

Updated and upgraded ubuntu
edit **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** and added:

allow-guest=false

greeter-hide-users=true

greeter-show-manual-login=true

```
sudo mv .xauthority .xauthority.bax

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

sudo restart lightdm
```

this did not fix the issue so:

ubuntu-bug lightdm

=============================

I have been searching all the login loop questions and have exhausted all avenues pointed out by the many answers.  It seems that so many people have this issue with the unity greeter.

PS: I have 2 video cards and drivers:

Intel HD Graphics 630

AMD Radeon Pro WX2100

Answer (score 0):

Definitely something to do with lightdm

I installed gdm3:

sudo apt-get install gdm

The system will login to my desktop and everything is normal.
Change to lightdm:

System goes into a login loop.